# split address to streetNumber, streetName and streetType

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

Here the [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/sufisokeyu/edit?js,console)
Here in code if you don't want to click on the link

```
var parseString = function (s) {
  var streetNumber = s.split(' ')[0];
  var streetName = s.split(' ')[1];
  var streetType = s.split(' ')[2];

  return {
    streetNumber: streetNumber,
    streetName: streetName,
    streetType: streetType,
  };
};
var address = "1498 Riedel Street";

console.log("Street Number: " + parseString(address).streetNumber);
console.log("Street Name: " + parseString(address).streetName);
console.log("Street Type: " + parseString(address).streetType);

address =  "4860 Dry Pine Bay Rd"

console.log("Street Number: " + parseString(address).streetNumber);
console.log("Street Name: " + parseString(address).streetName);
console.log("Street Type: " + parseString(address).streetType);
```

Now I want to split address in Number, Name and Type.

StreetType is following specific ISO format and is always found as last in the string.

The problem is when the Street Name have multiple spaces.
How can I split StreetName with multiple characters from the street Type

Comment: Even if your data is accurate, you may find instances where things just don't work. For example, in Tampa, Florida, USA, there is a roadway called "Boulevard". There is a North and South section of it, but it is not "North Blvd". It is "N Boulevard" or "S Boulevard". It has no "type".

Comment: Agreed, unless you're dealing with "sanitized" data, this is a complex task. What if the user enters directions, like "123 Main St SE"? There are services like smartystreets.com that deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
var address =  "4860 Dry Pine Bay Rd";
var split = address.split(" ");
var number = split[0];
var name = split[1];
for (var i = 2; i < split.length - 1; i++)
    name += " " + split[i];
var type = split[split.length - 1];
```

This assumes that street type does **not** contain spaces.

Alternatively you can use `slice()` and then `join()`.

```
var name =  split.slice(1, split.length - 1).join(" ");
```

This takes a subarray of `split` (excludes the first and the last element) and joins the subarray on the space.

Answer (score 0):

use [Array.shift()](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/shift) and [Array.pop()](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/pop) to grab the first and last elements, and then glue the remaining back together.

```
var parseAddress = function(addr){
    var r = {
        num: null,
        street: null,
        type: null
    };
    var addressComponents = addr.split(/\s/g);
    r.num = Number.parseInt(addressComponents.shift());
    r.type = addressComponents.pop();
    r.street = addressComponents.join(' ');
    return r;
};
```

jsbin: http://jsbin.com/zerega/edit?js,console